# How to allow a group of labels to grow together and to respectively shrink the input fields?

Tags: html, css, forms, label, input-field

I want to have a group of labels that take as much horizontal space as the widest label and at the same time all input fields should shrink to accommodate the larger labels. I need this since I deal with translations and cannot be sure how wide a certain label will be.

Something like this:

```css
form {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

label {
  width: 1%;
  display: table-cell;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-right: 1em;
}

input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.input-group {
  display: table-row;
}

* {
  line-height: 2em;
}

body {
  padding: 2em;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="input-group">
    <label for="name">Full name of your family and yourself</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="optional">
  </div>
   <div class="input-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="optional">
  </div>
    <div class="input-group">
    <label for="phone">Phone</label>
    <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="optional">
  </div>
</form>
```

You can check this in Codepen too:

http://codepen.io/aboutandre/pen/bZRjqB

But is it there a more elegant way to do this that is more generic and doesn't involve using tables (be as HTML or CSS)?

Answer (score 0):

How about specifying the width of the input fields to inherit from the desired/determining input field?
So for example if the name field is the determinant,make that have a width of 100% and and the other two elements -
width: inherit;

Comment: I didn't quite follow your answer. Could you please expand on it with an example?